# When recording video, how to set transformation (portrait, landscape, etc.) for video?

Tags: iphone, avfoundation, avcapturesession, avassetwriter

Should I use AVCaptureConnection's videoOrientation property, or set the transform property of the videoWriterInput, or something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like AVCaptureConnection's videoOrientation property sets the orientation as it's recording, while the transform property of the videoWriterInput will set a flag for the playback transform.